# Utilizar ArrayList de un RecyclerViewAdapter en otra Activity

Tags: java, android, android-studio

estoy intentando utilizar un ArrayList creado y rellenado en un RecyclerViewAdapter, para recorrerlo en otra Activity.
Probé a utilizar Intent, Getters, igualar un ArrayList a otro y nada me funciona.

Código del adaptador:

```
public class MyLenguajeRecyclerViewAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MyLenguajeRecyclerViewAdapter.ViewHolder> {

private final List<Lenguaje> lenguajeList;
private final OnLenguajeInteractionListener mListener;
private Context ctx;
final ArrayList<String> lenguajes = new ArrayList<>();


public MyLenguajeRecyclerViewAdapter(Context context, List<Lenguaje> items, OnLenguajeInteractionListener listener) {
    ctx = context;
    lenguajeList = items;
    mListener = listener;
}
```

Código dentro del adaptador en el cuál relleno el ArrayList:

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final ViewHolder holder, final int position) {
    holder.mItem = lenguajeList.get(position);
    holder.textViewNombre.setText(holder.mItem.getTitulo());
    holder.logo.setImageResource(holder.mItem.getIdImagen());
    holder.checkBoxLenguaje.setChecked(holder.mItem.isChecked());


    if (position % 2 == 0) {
        holder.mView.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(ctx, R.color.azulLigero));
    } else {
        holder.mView.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(ctx, R.color.azulCeleste));
    }


    holder.mView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            CheckBox cb = v.findViewById(R.id.checkBoxLenguaje);
            cb.setChecked(!cb.isChecked());
            TextView tv = v.findViewById(R.id.textViewLenguaje);

            if (cb.isChecked()) {
                if (!lenguajes.contains(tv.getText().toString())) {
                    lenguajes.add(tv.getText().toString());
                }
            } else if (!cb.isChecked()) {
                if (lenguajes.contains(tv.getText().toString())) {
                    lenguajes.remove(tv.getText().toString());                      
                }
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Código de la ActivityLenguajes en el cual quiero recorrer el ArrayList

```
            Empleado emp = new Programador(nombre, email, password, genero, fechaNacimiento, lenguajes);

            //for (int i = 0; i < lenguajes.size(); i++) {
            AlertDialog.Builder ad = new AlertDialog.Builder(LenguajesActivity.this);
            ad.setTitle("Lenguajes elegidos");
            ad.setMessage(emp.toString());
            ad.setCancelable(true);
            ad.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(LenguajesActivity.this, LoginActivity.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
                }
            });
            ad.show();
        }
        //}
```

Esta es la imagen que se muestra cuando ejecuto la ActivityLenguajes. Contiene un fragment en el que muestro la lista de lenguajes como se puede observar

[image]

Y en esta muestro la alerta en la cual muestro los datos del programador registrado y sus supuestos lenguajes. **Esta alerta se muestra al pulsar un botón en LenguajesActivity, y cuando le das a OK se va a LoginActivity.**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Añado captura del Debugger en el momento que estoy seleccionado los lenguajes.**

*Yo lo que quiero es pasar ese ArrayList (que en ese momento tiene un tamaño de 3), a la LenguajesActivity, la cual es su Contexto, para poder recorrerlo cuando le doy al botón seleccionar de la propia LenguajesActivity.*]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Para hacer lo mismo pero con idiomas, utiicé un ListView y me funciona correctamente, pero en este caso necesito utilizar el RecyclerView.

Gracias

Comment: los datos los guardas en una base de datos??

Comment: No, simplemente son para mostrar una vez finalizo el registro, al cerrar el programa se borran.
Si necesitas más detalles no dudes en decirlo, y gracias por el interés ^^.

Comment: Es mejor que en vez de llenar la lista en el adaptador lo hagas desde el activity o fragment

Comment: @Sergio, nada, ya probé de todas las formas que se me ocurrieron  + lo recomendado y sigue dando nullpointer.
Hacerlo con un RecyclerView es opcional, pero quiero hacerlo de esa forma si o si para aprenderlo.
Lo que quiero que haga es que una vez estoy en la ActivityLenguajes, seleccione los lenguajes, y al darle al botón Seleccionar me salga el AlertDialog y al darle a OK vuelva al Login Activity.

Os dejo link al repositorio que acabo de subir y a ver si me podéis echar una mano, si no pues lo doy por vencido xD

https://github.com/ZyZzY69/PMPD-TrabajoFInal.git

Gracias^^

Answer (score 0):

Si tienes los elementos en un ArrayList y estos los deseas enviar a otra `Activity`, puedes realizarlo mediante un Intent, primero asegura en este caso que tu objeto, en este caso Lenguaje implemente la clase Serializable:

```
public class Lenguaje implements Serializable {
```

Ahora mediante el Intent podrìas enviar los datos:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(LenguajesActivity.this, LoginActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("lenguajes", lenguajeList);
startActivity(intent);
```

y para recibir este ArrayList dentro de la Activity destino lo realizaràs de esta forma:

```
ArrayList<Lenguaje> lenguajeList = (ArrayList<Lenguaje>) getIntent().getSerializableExtra("lenguajes");
```

Comment: Hola! gracias por la respuesta, aunque por desgracia creo que no va a funcionar en mi caso. Acabo de editar el post principal con más información. Si puedes échale un ojo y si necesitas que ponga más código no dudes en pedírmelo.